# How do I subtract values in the SAME variable column in SPSS?

Tags: dataset, spss, subtraction

So I'm trying to create a new variable column of ''first differences'' by subtracting values in the SAME column but have no clue how to do so on SPSS. For example, in this picture:
[image]
1st value - 0 = 0 (obviously). 2nd value - 1st value =..., 3rd value - 2nd value =..., 4th value - 3rd value =... and so on.

Also, if there is a negative number, does SPSS allow me to log it/regress it? Once I find the first difference, I'm going to LOG it & then regress it. For context, the reason I'm doing this is  part of a bigger equation to find out how economic growth and a CHANGE in economic growth (hence the first difference and log) will affect the variable im studying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate differences between values in consecutive rows use this:

```
if $casenum>1 diffs = FinalConsumExp - lag(FinalConsumExp).
execute.
```

If you need help with additional problems please start a separate question for each problem.

HTH.